# Is it possible to create an alternate directory with incremented inode of an already existing file on a device?

Tags: android, memory, directory, inode

I am not sure if it is right question but is there a way of creating a new directory at some other location which also points to an existing file i.e (image or video) with incremented inode.
I am using android studio , what i want to do is create new directory or path which also points to already existing image, if user deletes the file the alternate path can be used to open the file.(if inode increments)
can it be done through java to provide alternate path to open existing file in gallery.

or i have to reach file itself by system calls.I dont know much about the particular process but i am curious so little explanation can be helpful.